# DR 2137 is not clear to me

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, c++17

In [DR 2137](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2137) we have the following text (emphasis is mine):

> It is not clear in code like the following that selecting a copy/move
>   constructor is the correct choice when an initializer list contains a
>   single element of the type being initialized, as required by issue
>   1467:
>
> ```
> #include <initializer_list>
> #include <iostream>
>
> struct Q {
>     Q() { std::cout << "default\n"; }
>     Q(Q const&) { std::cout << "copy\n"; }
>     Q(Q&&) { std::cout << "move\n"; }
>     Q(std::initializer_list<Q>) { std::cout << "initializer list\n"; }
> };
>
> int main() {
>     Q x = Q { Q() };
> }
> ```
>
> Here the intent is that `Q` objects can contain other `Q` objects, **but
>   this is broken by the resolution of issue 1467**.

I'd like to understand why the code above would be broken by the resolution of [issue 1467](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1467).

Comment: Well, the issue is whether `Q { Q() };` should invoke `Q(Q&&)` or `Q(std::initializer_list<Q>)`.  DR1467 makes it invoke `Q(Q&&)`, and DR2137 proposes that it invokes `Q(std::initializer_list<Q>)`.  Does that answer your question ? (if not then maybe go into more detail about your question)

Comment: @M.M This clearly answers my question. But why is the solution given by 2137 better than 1467? If you prefer, fill out an answer for the question, so that I can close the thread. Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't say why one is better than the other

Comment: For the discussion that led to 2137, see http://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23812. For a concrete example of this pattern, see https://github.com/dropbox/json11/issues/86.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DR 2147 has this statement: "the intent is that `Q` objects can contain other `Q` objects". Given that, it assumes that if the user constructs a `Q` from a braced-init-list containing other `Q`s, that the intent of the user is to call the `initializer_list` constructor.

Given that assumption, it is therefore "broken" to *not* call the `initializer_list` constructor, which 1467 would cause.

Whether you agree with this logic or not, that's the thinking behind 2147. It's also the thinking that permits [over.match.list] to prioritize `initializer_list` constructors over any other constructor type. So in that way, it is consistent.